# Mysql query insert with empty values

Tags: mysql

In a code i saw following code snippet,

```
INSERT INTO hospital () VALUES ()
```

I'm confussed by looking this.Is it ok.if so what it means. I saw it in a world recognized project.

Comment: Insert a new row with every column set to its default value.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you explain why use this.What's the purpose behind this with a example.

Comment: I'd guess that the row ID is set to auto-increment. By doing this you can create a row and retrieve the row ID and a set of default values ready for some further processing.

Comment: Yeah.It can be. In that code, after insering select that row by using orderd by... desc and returned.

Comment: Eh? Why not just use `mysqli::insert_id` or whatever language equivalent suits you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will insert a new row with all default values defined in the table.

To take into account (From the documentation)

> In strict mode, an error occurs if any column doesn't have a default value. Otherwise, MySQL uses the implicit default value for any column that does not have an explicitly defined default.

Full explanation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)